# r table for many columns

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

My dataset is like this.

```
   ID    Col_01    Col_02   Col_03    Col_04    Col_05    Col_06
   1     1         2        1         3         4         -9
   2     1         1        2         1         2          2
   3     2         4        1         1         1          1
   4     3         1        3         2        -9          4
   5     2         3        4         4         3          2
```

I like to create a summarized dataset where the number of 1s,2s,3s,4s, -9s in each column (Col_01-Col_06) are counted like this.

```
    Values    Col_01    Col_02   Col_03    Col_04    Col_05    Col_06   
    1         2         2        2         2         1         1
    2         2         1        1         1         1         2
    3         1         1        1         1         1         0
    4         0         1        1         1         1         1
   -9         0         0        0         0         1         1
```

So far I tried

```
    df %>%
      select(matches(^Col_\\d+$")) %>%
       summarise_all(funs(table))
```

but I get an error Col_05 must be of size 4 or 1 , not 5 as earlier column had size 4. and bunch of other warnings. Any suggestions how I can create table summary for all columns starting with Col_ in my dataset is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R you could do

```r
table(stack(df1,-1))
```

If you need a dataframe:

```
as.data.frame matrix(table(stack(df1,-1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Pivoting longer, counting, then pivoting wider is one option.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Col_")) %>% 
  count(name, value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, 
              values_from = n, 
              values_fill = 0)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 7
  value Col_01 Col_02 Col_03 Col_04 Col_05 Col_06
  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1     1      2      2      2      2      1      1
2     2      2      1      1      1      1      2
3     3      1      1      1      1      1      0
4     4      0      1      1      1      1      1
5    -9      0      0      0      0      1      1
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Col_01 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), Col_02 = c(2L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 3L), Col_03 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L), Col_04 = c(3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 4L), Col_05 = c(4L, 2L, 1L, -9L, 3L), Col_06 = c(-9L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Comment: for some reason I get an error, 'count(., name, value): object 'name' not found. I cant even run `starwars %>% count(species)` line, something messy on my end , r does not like count() function